# How to set custom avatar for users?

Tags: users, user-registration, avatar

I need to update custom image for users avatar on the time of registrations.

I've using `Pie-register` plugin and it will allow upload profile picture but saving image `url` in `user_meta` and when try to get using get_avatar it returning default avatar, but I need upload image as user avatar on all places. Like user profile page , in comment section etc.

Is this possible to display `user meta value` (image url) as user avatar for all users?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [`get_avatar_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/) filter to modify the avatar's url.

If all the relevant [`get_avatar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) calls,  have *user id* as an input argument, then it's easy to get the corresponding user's meta value, with [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/), within the filter's callback.

Otherwise we need to handle all possible input cases, for  `get_avatar( $some_input )`, as it supports:

- user id,
- user email,
- gravatar md5 hash,
- `WP_User` object,
- `WP_Post` object
- `WP_Comment` object.

We can look into the [`get_avatar_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_data/) function, to get an idea how to write such checks.

An alternative, to determine the user id from the `get_avatar()` input, we might try to fetch the md5 hash from the generated gravatar url and use it to determine the user id from it. Maybe store the md5 email hash for each user.
The `found_avatar` argument might also help, as it's true if the avatar was found for the given user.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But I think in this case I need to pass user ID in get_avatar() ? I've different profile picture for each users saved in user meta and I want to use those images for each user as profile picture.